# How to make fancyvrb's \DefineShortVerb work in other commands?

Tags: fancyvrb

I'm using the `fancyvrb` package with the `\DefineShortVerb{\|}`. However, using `|` inside of any command doesn't work. MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\DefineShortVerb{\|}

\begin{document}

\section{|Pipe| doesn't work here}
THe |pipe| works here just fine. \marginpar{|Pipe| doesn't work here either.}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to define a `ShortVerb` and have it work inside of other commands? I wasn't able to find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: @egreg what about a workaround? another package?

Comment: It doesn't depend on how many packages you load: verbatim material cannot go inside the argument to another command. If the characters to appear verbatim satisfy some restrictions, it can be done; but if you want arbitrary material, you're out of luck.

Comment: @egreg that's what I was afraid of.

Comment: `fancyvrb` comes with a `\SaveVerb` command and `UseVerb` command that let's you work around these sorts of issues.  But as @egreg has said, the short aswer is "no".

Comment: @Jeremy Can you be more specific on what you want to appear "verbatim"? Some real world examples.

Comment: The example I gave above is pretty close to what I want to do; a section command or a in a marginpar command is what I was trying to accomplish this afternoon. For this simple task a simple `\texttt` would work.

Comment: @Jeremy So use `\texttt`; I can see that `|pipe|` seems less work, but it's *not* good LaTeX markup. You can say `\newcommand{\jv}{\texttt}` and use `\jv{pipe}`, which is even better, because it will distinguish the object by its function among other usages of `\texttt`.

Comment: @egreg The reason I used `|pipe|` was because I got tired of typing `\texttt{pipe}` as you so wisely assumed. Is the `ShortVerb` discouraged because it isn't clear what is being done?

Comment: @egreg there's lots of alternatives in the uk faq.  `\texttt` is of course the ideal, but it's hardly in the spirit of the question.  there is even the `cprotect` package, which is a splendid example of dark tex arts...

Comment: @wasteofspace `cprotect` writes an auxiliary file for each usage. While it's a great piece of software, I'm not wanting to use it. Just do as Jill Knuth once recommended: "Don't use footnotes in your book, Don." `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

If you're really wedded to the idea of using verbatim and since you're already using `fancyvrb` you can do the following:'

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
\SaveVerb{verb:example}|\this is saved|
\fbox{\UseVerb{verb:example}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This will also work in a `\section` command if you prepend `\protect\UseVerb{verb:example}`.  Though I'm not sure how this will effect TOC.

Otherwise, I would stick with @egreg's suggestions.

Comment: This is a good idea if I had to reuse the same thing many times, but is a little much for one-off formatting.